# Can I prevent ListBox.RefreshItem(object item) from removing and re-adding the object?

Tags: c#, listbox

The issue I am having is that when I update my object, the ListBox automatically removes and then re-adds the object to the list, thus calling the index and value changed events. I was able to prevent this by creating a custom ListBox control and when the PropertyChangedEvent was called, I would raise a flag that would prevent those events in the base class from being called. What is happening now is that my entire reference is being replace by a new reference and unless I re-select the item in the ListBox, I have the wrong reference.

What I basically want to do, is to change the Display Value in my object and then have it update only the text in the list box. I do not want it to remove and to re-add the object/reference/whatever it does. It's quite annoying.

Here is the example code I am working with...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myListBox1.SelectedValueChanged += this.onchange;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("z"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("a"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("b"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("f"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("n"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("h"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("p"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("t"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("c"));
        this.myListBox1.Add(new strobj("q"));
    }

    private void onchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }

    int i = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (this.myListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            strobj item = (strobj)this.myListBox1.SelectedItem;
            item.Name1 = i++.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public partial class MyListBox
{
    public MyListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Add(strobj item)
    {
        item.OnNameChanged += this.MyDispalyMemberChanged;
        this.Items.Add(item);
    }

    bool refreshing = false;
    public void MyDispalyMemberChanged(strobj itemChanged)
    {
        this.refreshing = true;
        this.RefreshItem(this.Items.IndexOf(itemChanged));
        this.refreshing = false;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.refreshing)
        {
            base.OnSelectedValueChanged(e);
        }
    }
}

class strobjCollection : List<strobj>
{
    NameChangeEventHandler NameChangedEvent;
}

delegate void NameChangeEventHandler(strobj sender);

public class strobj
{
    internal NameChangeEventHandler OnNameChanged;

    private string _Name1;
    public string Name1
    {
        get { return this._Name1; }
        set
        {
            this._Name1 = value;
            if (this.OnNameChanged != null)
            {
                this.OnNameChanged(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public int i = 0;
    public string str = "p";

    public strobj(string name)
    {
        this._Name1 = name;
    }

    public strobj()
    {
        this._Name1 = "You did not create this object";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this._Name1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface was made for.

Instead of raising your custom event, you'd raise the PropertyChanged event with the name of the property you changed set in the event args and the listbox would update.

[See MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but this method still removes and re-adds the object to list and calling the SelectedValueChanged Event twice. first time, changing it to null and the second time changing it to the new value. Now the reference that I pulled out earlier, no longer references the currently selected item, most likely because in my implimented version, I override the == operator. The only thing that I want to happen is to update the text. I don't want the item to be removed and re-add.